# dynamically creating key and values in dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to Python. I am here reading several lines in a file having a format

```
    121212-pr-ba-su_re;m1;1;10000
```

I have extracted (pr-ba-su) content using split function. Please see the code which i wrote. I wish to store the Prefix-base-suffix as a key and its value as ID (which is extracted in the first line of loop) in a dictionary. (I want to replace the key with value in another list. Therefore, i am trying to create a dictionary.)

```
    data ={}    
    f = open('var_test.txt')
    for line in f:
            part,m,t,ID = line.split(';',3)
            partnumb,r = part.split('_',1)
            item,prefix,base,suffix =partnumb.split('-',3)
            data[prefix'-'base'-'suffix] =ID
```

But i am getting an error as Syntax Error

```
        data(getattr([prefix'-'base'-'suffix])) =PID
                          ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried using getattr()function,and update function but no avail.Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `data[prefix + '-' + base + '-' + suffix] = ID` is how you concatenate strings.

Comment: @makino that's not how you concatenate strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `data[prefix'-'base'-'suffix] =ID` is your problem. It is not valid Python syntax.

You could get the results you expect by substituting for this line

`data["{}-{}-{}".format(prefix, base, suffix)] = ID`